# How to get list of all variables inside a function?

Tags: python

I have a python function

```
def read_info():
    f = open("./info.txt", "r")
    print(f.read())
```

I want to list all the variables used inside the function, e.g. here `f`.

now i try

```
$ python
>> from read_info import read_info
>> dir(read_info)
>>> dir(read_info)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

I tried `dir(read_info)` but it does not show `f`. (As we can see in the above output of dir(read_info) we dont see the variable f)

Comment: You can't do it without actually executing the function since variable are created a runtime.

Comment: but dir shows the defined functions etc

Comment: I assume you are talking about `dir()` on an `import`ed module — `import`ing executes all the function, class, and module-level definitions in it.

Comment: *but dir shows the defined functions etc.*  Yes, because the `def` statement has been executed, so function objects have been created.  Although the code is compiled to intermediate language, the variable `f` inside the function will not be created until the function runs.

Comment: And `dir(read_info)` tells you nothing at all about your code.  It only tells you about the function `read_info`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From inside the function, you can use `locals()` to get a dict of local variables and their values.

From outside the function, use `my_func.__code__.co_varnames` to get the names of local variables and parameters:

```
>>> def f(x):
...   y = 42
...
>>> f.__code__.co_varnames
('x', 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside the function with [locals()](https://appdividend.com/2019/08/01/python-locals-example-locals-function-tutorial/#:%7E:text=Python%20locals()%20is%20an,global%20namespace%20of%20the%20module.). In your case

```
locals()["f"]
```

will get you what you need. Note that except in very particular cases, this is not suggested and likely to lead to code smells.

Comment: i dont know the name of var eg: f

Comment: what about looping through the locals() then?

Comment: `list(locals())`